# How to Enable ctr + scrollwheel to zoom in Google Maps Api

Tags: angular, google-maps

Hi im using Google Maps API https://angular-maps.com/, and i want to zoom only while pressing ctrl + scrolling with the scrollwheel. Reading the documentation I have found this:

> gestureHandling    This setting controls how gestures on the map are
>   handled. Allowed values:
>
> 'cooperative' (Two-finger touch gestures pan and zoom the map.
>   One-finger touch gestures are not handled by the map.)  'greedy' (All
>   touch gestures pan or zoom the map.)  'none' (The map cannot be panned
>   or zoomed by user gestures.)  'auto' [default] (Gesture handling is
>   either cooperative or greedy, depending on whether the page is
>   scrollable or not. Type: |||
>
> Default value: auto

so in my code i added :

```
<agm-map
    [latitude]="lat" 
    [longitude]="lng"
    [zoom]="zoom"
    [gestureHandling]="cooperative"
    [mapTypeControl]="true"
    [mapTypeControlOptions]="mapType"
    >
```

but is not working, it does not ask me to press ctrl to zoom.

Answer (score 11):

Setting `[scrollwheel]="null"` seems to work for now.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, a combination of these answers worked.

In my case, I had neither `[scrollWheel]` or `[gestureHandling]` on my `agm-map` control initially.

Both `[scrollWheel]="null"` and `[gestureHandling]="'cooperative'"` must be set in API  v3.32+ for this to work as desired.

As a side note, setting a specific API version is a cheap workaround to 'breaking' changes.  Always strive to ride the wave (even if just in front of the end-of-support deadline).

[User n0minal figures this out on AGM github](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1411#issuecomment-424844197)

Answer (score 2):

As [Martti Käärik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150166/martti-k%C3%A4%C3%A4rik) said you can use:

```
[scrollwheel]="null"
```

or

```
[scrollwheel]="false"
```

as input of the agm-map. The difference between the two is that the first one allows to zoom in and out with CMD+scroll or CTRL+scroll and shows a message about it on the map during the page scrolling, the second one instead does not show any message and does not allow you to zoom with scroll or CMD/CTRL+scroll but you can control the map zoom with the buttons given by `[zoomControl]="true"` as well.

If you need a reference for scrollwheel and other input you can see [here](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap#scrollwheel).

Answer (score 1):

I Found an answer on the AGM chat that seems to resolve this issue.

Set you version to 4 in the Module like :

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: 'your_key',
  apiVersion: "4"
}),
```

Haven't tried it myself but it worked for that user. Give it a try and get back if it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for sharing, how to disable zoom on scroll and enable it only with ctrl? cause with that solution it still zooming when scrolling

Comment: That is the coopeative setting. So specify that in you code like: [gestureHandling]="cooperative"

Comment: Latest version of today is 3.32 (experimental), setting to version 4 throws back an error.

Comment: I've tried with 3.32, 3.33 and 4. None did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the next:

```
[gestureHandling]="'coopeative'"
```

Comment: The user already showed he tried that. It's literally in the code block.

Comment: @FrankerZ he set "coopeative" ( in this case angular watch for variable), but gestureHandling mast get string.

" 'coopeative' " = string

Comment: Then you should say that. It would be a *much better* answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was resolved at https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1411

A solution would be:

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: '-bQ',
      apiVersion: '3.31'
    }),
```

Basicly downgrading the maps api fixed that but not sure why.

Still, as said before, do not forget to add `[gestureHandling]="'cooperative'"`

Comment: The only one that actually worked for me, but the map style is a bit uglier.